# How to enable expo video sound to play when silent switch is enabled on iPhone on React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

So I am trying to have my video play the sound even when the Iphone has its silent switch activated. The docs say to look at the audio docs which I have but am still getting nothing to work. Am I suppose to somehow connect my Video to the expo Audio api to be able to use those controls?

Currently I have this and it is not working:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function test() {
            await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            });
            const playbackObject = new Audio.Sound();
        }
        
        test();
    });
```

```
<Video
                    ref={video}
                    style={styles.videoView}
                    source={{
                        // uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
                        uri: 'http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8',
                    }}
                    useNativeControls
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    isLooping
                    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run a silent sound and make it playAsync. It can work

```
useEffect(() => {
    const setAudioMode = async () => {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            staysActiveInBackground: true,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
            shouldDuckAndroid: false,
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        })
        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
            const playSilentSound = async () => {
                const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
                    require("./assets/silent-sound.mp3")
                )
                await sound.playAsync()
                await sound.pauseAsync()
            }
            playSilentSound()
        }
    }
    setAudioMode()
}, [])
```